# Time of calculating Mertens function.

Tags: number-theory, computational-mathematics, mobius-function

There is Mertens function:
$$M(x)=\sum_{n \le x}\mu(n)$$

> How to calculate time of computing value of $M(N)$ for particular $N$?

I would like for example find that time using this formula:
$$M(x)=1-\sum_{d\ge2}M(\frac{x}{d})$$

If we suppose that time to compute $M(x)$ is $O(f(x))$ then we get $f(x)=f(\frac{x}{2})+f(\frac{x}{3})+...$ And we need to find formula for $f$

Neverthelss i think i have done something wrong.

I hope for help.

Comment: what is $\mu(n)$ ? Do you want the complexity in time or in terms of elementary arithmetic operations ?

Comment: One can compute $M(n)$ for a particular n in about time $O(n^{2/3})$. See for example https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1047565447, the article "Computing the summation of the Möbius function" in the journal of Experimental Mathematics. If you are computing many values, you should build a table of factorizations by building the primes up to $X$, and then just build the table. This can be done in time $O(X^{1 + \epsilon})$.